# Unable to hide scroll bar + form acting weird

Tags: html, css

I tried to find a solution in previous questions but overflow:hidden; isn't working for me. There's a lab background image with a potion on it at the top here:
 [www.walterbar.co.il](http://walterbar.co.il/), the potion is supposed to open an overlay with a form. You can see there's some scrolling bar that appears and disappears really quick.

Also, the X button is acting weird when I insert overflow in the Custom CSS plug-in.

Another issue is that for some reason the form won't align to the center (not in the overlay window and not at the bottom).

Any idea why? I apologize for the weird language. :-)
Thanks in advance!

The HTML code of the overlay:

```
<a href="#contact_popup" class="fancybox">
<img id="walterbarpotion" src="http://walterbar.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/animation_SMALL.gif" style="max-width:250%">
</a>
 <div style="display:none;background-color:black;" class="fancybox-hidden">
    <div id="contact_popup">
        [contact-form-7 id="342" title="צור קשר"]
    </div>
 </div>
```

The form's HTML:

```
<style>
input[type="email"]::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear; 
  color: gray;
}

input[type="email"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
  opacity: 0;
}
input[type="phone"]::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear; 
  color: gray;
}

input[type="phone"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
  opacity: 0;
}
}
input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear; 
  color: gray;
}

input[type="text"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder  {
  opacity: 0;
}


</style>
<center> 

<label for=".elementor-6 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5m0lukt .wpcf7 input[type="text"]"><input type=text text* your-name placeholder="שם" required </input></label>

<label for= ".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-tel.wpcf7-validates-as-required.wpcf7-validates-as-tel* your-email"> <input type="phone" tel* tel-196 input placeholder="טלפון" required</input></label>

<label for=".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-email.wpcf7-validates-as-required.wpcf7-validates-as-email"]"><input type=email email* your-email placeholder="אימייל" ID= "email" </input></label>

[submit "דברו איתנו"]
</center>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit {
  width: 20% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  background-color: #316e35 !important;
  color: white !important;
  font-family: open sans hebrew condensed;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: 900;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100em;
  display: inline-block;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 158.5px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 60%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  width: 20% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  background-color: white !important;
  color: #316e35 !important;
  font-family: open sans hebrew condensed;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: 900;
  animation: bounce 1s;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100em;
  display: inline-block;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 158.5px;
}

[placeholder]:focus {
  background-color: rgba(221,221,221,0.8);
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  font-family: open sans hebrew condensed;
  font-style: italic;
}

body .cf7-style input[type=”text”]:focus,
body .cf7-style input[type=”email”]:focus,
body .cf7-style textarea:focus {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  color: black;
}

body .cf7-style input[type=”text”]:focus,
body .cf7-style input[type=”email”]:focus,
body .cf7-style textarea:focus {
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

[placeholder] {
  width: 25% !important;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8) !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  color: #333333 !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center !important;
  border-radius: 999em !important;
  display: inline-block;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  font-family: open sans hebrew condensed !important;
  font-style: italic;
  min-width: 164px;
}

[placeholder]:focus {
  background-color: rgba(221,221,221,0.8) !important;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease !important;
  font-family: open sans hebrew condensed !important;
  font-style: italic !important;
  border: 2px solid #316e35 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE !important;
  min-width: 164px;
}

#wp-sticky-menu.wp-sticky-menu.headroom.slide {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center !important;
}

.wpsm-logo a {
  display: none;
}

.menu-image-title {
  font-family: Amatic SC;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.elementor-section-content-top>.elementor-container>.elementor-row>.elementor-column>.elementor-column-wrap
:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url("http://walterbar.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Divider.png");
  height: 73px;
  top: 700px;
}
.elementor-7 .elementor-element.elementor-element-jnflk99 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}

#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group{
  width:100% !important}

#fanctbox {overflow:hidden;}

#fancybox-wrap {overflow:hidden;}
#fancybox-outer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
border: none;
overflow:hidden;
width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#contact_popup, #fancybox-content{
border:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code.

Comment: I edited my main post and tried to find anything relevant to the questions. I'm not an expert when it comes to coding, so I thought it will be much easier if you could see the live website at the link I provided. By the way, I'm pretty certain some coding there isn't necessary, I had a few issues when I tried to design the website with some CSS and when I managed to get the things I wanted I didn't wanna touch anything.

Comment: I think you have a typo `#fanctbox {overflow:hidden;}`

Comment: What do you mean by acting weird?

Comment: I see what you mean..further edits done to my response accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden!important` to `#fancybox-content > div`.

Remove `overflow:hidden` from `#fancybox-outer` to display the full X button.

Set `padding:0` in `#contact_popup, #fancybox-content` and add `margin:auto`.

Set `display:block` for `.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit`.

If you are using Chrome or Firefox you can right-click any element and select Inspect Element from the context menu. You can directly make changes and see the effect. (The changes won't be saved).

Comment: Although I now have another annoying issue with the form. The form at the bottom of the website (Same code as the one at the fancybox) keeps making the sticky menu pop out when you hover the submit button. It happens because of the  display:block.

Comment: You could try adding an id, or differentiating by referring to a distinct parent element in the css, for the first submit button, and use that to set `display:block!important`, so the original css for the submit buttons need not be changed.

Comment: Or do you need centering for the second submit button as well? One hacky alternative could be adding a left margin instead, to push it to the center.

Comment: Need them all centered. So adding left margins won't be different for every browser & window size?

Comment: Actually, try using the original solution above but add `!important`. I looked at it and it seemed the button was shifting left on hover, so I figured perhaps it was reverting to inline-block. If that does not fix it, maybe we should move this to a chat :) Otherwise I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the fancybox-content you set a div with inline style="width:auto;height:auto;**overflow: auto**;position:relative;" 
set the overflow to overflow: hidden to prevent the scrollbar flash when you open the form.

To disable the scroll on body on form opening using jquery:

```
$('.walterbarpotion').click( function(){

    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');   

});
```

To set the scroll active again when closing 1st add a class or id to button and so:

```
$('#fancybox-overlay,#button_id').click( function(){

    $('body').css('overflow','scroll'); 

});
```

This is not perfect because I need to integrate it in the form check system to prevent the scrollbar showing in case of unsuccessful form check. Hope can help you to understand how it can be work.

Answer (score 0):

The overflow form is being animated by a jquery script, changing the height dynamically and finally set the height to auto. When the height is being animated in pixels quickly, it is causing an overflow and a scroll bar.

insert this in your script tag

```
$("#walterbarpotion").click(function(){$("#fancybox-content").css({"overflow":"hidden !important"})})
```